# How to get stack mesh orientation in Abaqus

Tags: python, stack, mesh, direction, abaqus

I'm struggling with finding the mesh stack orientations in Abaqus 2021 in a 2D mesh. I'd like to get them via a python script but there is no direct function. Does anayone know where this information is saved or how the meshing module defines the orientation in a 2D quadrilateral mesh?
The Abaqus CAE can display arrows showing the stack direction (see image), so this information should exist anywhere.

[Display of mesh stack orientation in Abaqus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHBO4.png)

I've looked for some dependencies within the element labels or element face labels, but didn't find any pattern. The manual says that Abaqus uses a "reference face" for defining the orientation. But I think this isn't valid for 2D meshes.